# Text To Speech in Dialog, weird behavior

Tags: android

The code opens a Dialog , in which a user entered `EditText` is converted to speech using `TTS` and the output is played.

```
 final   EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input);


    builder.setPositiveButton("SAVE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myAppCache/");
            //if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdirs();
            //}


            HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap();
            String toSpeak = input.getText().toString();
            t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

            String destFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myAppCache/wakeUp.wav";

            myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, toSpeak);
            t1.synthesizeToFile(toSpeak, myHashRender, destFileName);
            t1.stop();
            t1.shutdown();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Play", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String toSpeak = input.getText().toString();
            t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);



        }
    });

    builder.show();
}
```

And obviously there are two buttons in the Dialog, `setPositiveButton` and `setnegativeButton` , positive button saves the output as a `.wav` file , also plays the output. 
the negative button also plays the output. But 
`t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);`
does not produce any output in the positive button. What is causing this? Anything to take care while using Dialogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nothing to do with Dialogs, the problem is you are telling it to stop!

The call to `speak()` is non-blocking. From the API:

> The synthesis might not have finished (or even started!) at the time when this method returns.

Your code is:

```
START SPEAKING -> t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                  String destFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myAppCache/wakeUp.wav";

                  myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, toSpeak);
                  t1.synthesizeToFile(toSpeak, myHashRender, destFileName);
STOP SPEAKING ->  t1.stop();
```

So after you tell it to start you do a few more things, then tell it to stop - most likely before any sound has even been produced.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for stopping by to answer, btw where should I stop this ?

Comment: I've been after this for 2days, indebted to you :) , are you in G+ ?

Comment: Only stop it if you want the speech to stop - otherwise let it run its course and it will stop automatically when it's out of things to say. Call the `shutdown` method when you've finished with TTS - e.g. in `onPause()` for the activity.

Comment: No, but glad to be of assistance. Nice to know you sweated a bit before calling for help! :)

Comment: Yes, nothing becomes easy before it becomes tough, . . . any other way to keep in touch :) ?

Comment: Also, I tried adding a string that was lengthy, but it stopped just after speaking first 3 words? Can I use .mp3 instead ? would that fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough experience with TTS to help with that one - I assume nothing is showing up in Logcat?